# Derivation of Margolus-Levitin bound on the Quantum Speed Limit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In their derivation of the [Margolus-Levitin](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9707060) bound on the "quantum speed limit" the authors make use of a trigonometric inequality

$\cos x \ge 1-\frac{2}{\pi}(x+\sin x), \quad \forall x\ge0$

Is there an intuitive reason why this inequality is used? It seems such an arbitrary choice. Failing that, how do you prove this inequality?